# Vertical and horizontal components of forces and vectors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, gravity, forces, vectors

I'm getting a bit confused when finding components of vectors and forces.

In problems for vectors, I've always known that if you want to get the components of a vector, you would use the following:

[image]

---

Recently we've started working with Forces in homework problems.

This diagram is from one of my homework problems, which they want me to draw the free body diagram:

[image]

Here is the free body diagram given by the homework solution:

[image]

---

What I don't understand is why would I be using $m_{2}gsin(\theta)$ instead of $m_{2}gcos(\theta)$ when finding the X-component of the gravitational force of $m_{2}$.

Force *is* a vector, so why wouldn't you use  $m_{2}gcos(\theta)$? Are the rules different when dealing with forces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you define the angle. In this diagram you define the angle with respect to the horizontal and take the x-axis along the slope. So the x-component of of gravitational force comes out to be $m_2gsin\theta$. If you define the angle $\theta$ with respect to the vertical, then you would see $m_2gcos\theta$ as the x-component of the gravitational force. So it all depends on how you define the angle of slope.

Comment: Oh I see, so if I defined $\theta$ as being between $m_{2}g$ and $m_{2}gsin(\theta)$, *then* I would treat $m_{2}gcos(\theta)$ as the horizontal component of the force vector. Correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The formula for horizontal or vertical will depend on the angle given. In the diagram:

-The horizontal component can be found using the two angles:
Using angle A:

```
                CosA = adjacent/hypotoneuse= b/c
                 Therefore, b=c*cosA
```

Using angle B:

```
                 SinB= opposite/hypotoneuse= b/c
                   Therefore, b=c*sinA
```

As you can see, the horizontal component can be found using any of the two formulas. Horizontal component does NOT always use the cos function

Likewise, in your diagram,

sin(theeta)=opposite/hypotoneuse

therefore, opposite= hypotoneuse* sin(theeta)= m2gsin(theeta)

Always try to look at your problem in terms of a triangle with an opposite and adjacent side

Quick tip: the side the given angle touches uses the cos function (as in your problem). The other side uses the sine function

Answer (score 1):

That's an easy mistake to make! Think about the definition of $cos$ that you learned in freshman/sophomore geometry class - Adjacent over Hypotenuse. Notice in the freebody diagram that $m_2g \cos\theta$ is indeed adjacent to $\theta$